# Salesforce's Metadata API .describe() method missing many fields compared to .read()

Tags: python, salesforce, metadata, simple-salesforce, sfdc-metadata-api

When I use simple-salesforce's Metadata api read method `_sf.mdapi.CustomObject.read(sf_object_name)`, I get what seems to be a full list of fields from my object. However, if I use the describe method `getattr(_sf, sf_object_name).describe()`, the metadata returned is missing dozens of fields. Why is that the case for the same object?

I'd prefer to use .describe(), since it returns usable `picklistValues` vs. .read(), which sometimes gives a `valueSetName` that doesn't include the actual picklist values, just the name of a valueSet which I'd have to re-query for.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata read returns the "real" object definition plus lots of things you probably don't care about (listviews, action overrides, compact layouts, validation rules). It's aimed at admins/Devs that need to modify system configuration.

Describe will respect the field permissions you have so if there's stuff missing - somebody needs to fix your profile. Field level security, license for managed packages if there are any managed fields, if the field is a lookup you also need Read right to the object looked up... It's different use case aimed at giving you quick info what you can do (read/edit data, not metadata). And you don't need to be admin to run describes

Comment: Thanks. It's strange - I'm a System Administrator, also checked all field level security and they're definitely set to where I should be able to access them (and indeed, when I go to the object in Salesforce, I can read and edit many of the fields that aren't coming through `describes`).

Comment: You'll be surprised. Remove the right to read a field and then try to query it over API (not in Apex & execute anonymous, in the query editor). Even as sysadmin